# Saving urlretrieve in to zip file python

Tags: python, zip, urllib

Trying to save a xml file to a into a zip file, but I'm getting an error with the directory. I have the following code:

```
if not os.path.exists(log_file_path):
    os.makedirs(log_file_path)

for s in xml_list:
    parent_file = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name, "w")
    urllib.urlretrieve(log_repository_url + "/r.xml", zip_file_name + "\\r.xml")
    parent_file.close()
```

The error is saying I don't have r.xml in the zip file. Shouldn't this code create the .xml file and write to it? If not, how should I proceed?

Thank you!

Comment: That's not how archive files actually work, that's only how Explorer fakes them.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question**: The error is saying I don't have r.xml in the zip file.

You have to write it to your `ZipFile`, for instance:

```
with ZipFile(zip_file_name, 'w') as myzip:
    local_filename, headers = 
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(log_repository_url + "/r.xml")
    myzip.write(local_filename, arcname="r.xml")
```

> Python » 3.6.1 Documentation:
>
> - [urllib.request.urlretrieve](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve)
> - [zipfile.ZipFile.write](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.write)